# Get list of commits by user with the GitLab API

Tags: gitlab

I can successfully access info about a user with this command:

```
curl http://gitlab.$INTERNAL_SERVER.com/api/v3/\
users/$USER_ID\?private_token\=$GITLAB_TOKEN
```

However, I can not find the API endpoint for getting a list of the commits that the user has pushed to the GitLab server. Does a URL with this info exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, such an API endpoint does not exist. Essentially the best I've been able to come up with is this flow:

1. find all the projects the user is involved with (not 100% simple in itself)
2. then get commits for that project
3. THEN filter those commits based on useremail.

I am using [java-gitlab-api](https://github.com/timols/java-gitlab-api) to access the Gitlab server, so don't have curl samples handy (sorry!).

Comment: Side question - do you perhaps now what exactly `getLastCommits` returns? I have not been able to find documentation for such a call (not even sure if it is a Gitlab API endpoint, or a convenience function supplied by the java lib

Comment: theoretically, doesn't this require fetching every commit, since the user could have activity on every project and you fetch all commits for the project?

Comment: @dres - I have not worked on this in quite a while, and the gitlab APIs were evolving rather aggressively - so please take my reply with a pinch of salt. To answer your comment - yes, that is possible. If I remember correctly, I had a time-base limit in my code, so I would only retrieve commits for the last 7 days or something like that.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you can get a list of commits by using the Events endpoint

```
data = requests.get(host + "/api/v4/users/{id}/events".format(id=user_id),
                                    params={"action": "pushed"})
```

And you can chain that by updating `params` to

```
params.update({"before": before_date})
```

Where `before date` can be the last element in data, and you can loop continuously to get all commits by user from a specific date

Comment: I tried to get the commits using your way (Events API). However, if there are more than 1 commit in the push, it will always show the first commit and the last 'commit sha'. Because of that, all the commits cannot be found this way.

Comment: Your comment possibly will help improve some crawler I use. Thank you and take my up vote

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Python script that does what @demaniak suggest. Enjoy

```
import requests
import ujson as json
header ={...}
def get_all_commits_gitlab(project_id, username):
    json_loads_of_commit = []
    f_date = "2022-01-01T00:00:42.000+01:00"
    params = {"until": f_date}
    url_p = "https://gitlab.xxx.xx/api/v4/projects/%d/\
        repository/commits" % project_id
    r = requests.get(url_p, params, headers=header)
    c = 0
    while r.status_code == 200:
        jsLoad = json.loads(r.content)
        newDate = jsLoad[-1]["committed_date"]
        if (params["until"] == newDate):
            break
        user_commits = []
        for cm in jsLoad:
            if cm["author_name"] == username:
                user_commits.append(cm)
                c += 1
        json_loads_of_commit.append(user_commits)
        params["until"] = newDate
        r = requests.get(url_p, params, headers=header)
    print("project %d: %d commits by user %s, \
        the first one %s" % (project_id, c, username, newDate))
    return json_loads_of_commit
```